# Comparing two strings not working (?)

Tags: php, arrays, string, compare

I know this must be a really easy-to-solve question but, as a semi-newbie, is driving me nuts.

I have a txt files with several lines. Elements in every line are separated by |. After every line there's a carriage return.

I'm just trying to loop through these lines and if the first element of any line matches with a certain string, then some stuff must be done with that particular line .

```
$mystring = 'some string with spaces (or not)';
$myarray = explode("\n", file_get_contents('myfile.txt'));
for($x = 0; $x < count($myarray); $x++) {
    $myline = explode("|", $myarray[$x]);
    if ($myline[0] == $mystring) {
        //do things
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, I can't get it to work :( Any suggestions?

**Edit to add more info**:

Let's suppose my reference string is

```
$mystring = 'Spider-man: Homecoming';
```

And let's suppose that one line in txt file is:

> Spider-man: Homecoming|Marvel and Sony movie, releasing july 2017

So, as stated in the code, I'll have

```
$myline[0] = 'Spider-man: Homecoming';
```

For some reason, the code is not considering $myline[0] and $mystring equals.

Comment: and does this string `some string with spaces (or not)` is really exists in your file ?

Comment: show some real input data, the actual `$mystring` value and some fragment of `$myarray`

Comment: @hassan I edited the question to add a little more info.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest I edited the question to add a little more info.

Comment: works fine, https://3v4l.org/tARFP , make sure that you are properly load your source file;

Comment: @hassan It works with string stored in a variable as in your example, but it doesn't work when loading text from file. The file is properly loaded (warning/error messages should be displayed if not properly loaded) and I can even echo $myline[0] and $mystring and they are the same!! But when comparing them, nothing happens. It's driving me nuts.

Comment: @hassan Thanks for your time, I found a solution, as showed below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the solution.

```
$mystring = 'some string with spaces (or not)';
$myarray = explode("\n", file_get_contents('myfile.txt'));
for($x = 0; $x < count($myarray); $x++) {
    $myline = explode("|", $myarray[$x]);
    if (preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z]/", "", $myline[0]) == preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z]/", "", $mystring)) {
        //do things
    }
}
```

For some reason (I guess the explode elements has some aditional characteres, like spaces or whatever) the comparison wasn't working. Now with preg_replace, it works!